# Rationality of $Y^2Z = X^3 + X^2Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I came across the following example when reading  Silverman:

Example 3.7 Let $V$ be the variety

$$V : Y^2Z = X^3 + X^2Z$$

and consider the rational maps

$$\psi : \mathbb{P}_1 → V, \psi = [(S^2 − T^2)T, (S^2 − T^2)S, T^3],$$
$$\varphi : V → \mathbb{P}_1, \varphi= [Y,X].$$

Here $\psi$ is a morphism, while $\varphi$ is not regular at $[0, 0, 1]$. Not coincidentally, the
point $[0, 0, 1]$ is a singular point of $V$; see (II.2.1). We emphasize that although the
compositions $\varphi \circ \psi$ and $\psi \circ \varphi$ are the identity map wherever they are defined, the
maps $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are not isomorphisms, because $\varphi$ is not a morphism.

It seems to me that although $\varphi$ is not a morphism, the two maps defined above imply that $\mathbb{P}_1$ is birational to $V$ (since they define isomorphisms  between $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $V\[0,0,1]$). On the other hand, $K(\mathbb{P}_1)=K(X)$ is purely transcendental, but $K(V)\cong K(X, \sqrt{X^3+X^2})$ is not, so $\mathbb{P}_1$ cannot be birational to $V$.

I would appreciate it if someone could point out the mistake in my argument. Thanks!

Comment: A hint: $K(V)$ could be (in fact, is) generated by an element other than $x$. Try to find another element $\alpha \in K(V)$ such that $x$ and $y$ are both rational functions (in fact, polynomials) in $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. Indeed, $K(V)\cong K(X,\sqrt{X^3+X^2})=K(X,\sqrt{X+1})=K(\sqrt{X+1})$ since $X=(\sqrt{X+1})^2-1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Another hint: take the generator for $K(\mathbb{P}^1)$ and pull it back by $\varphi$. (Note that this should be done on an affine open.)